# OpenFL: Array has no field sortOn

Tags: haxe, openfl

I'm using OpenFL and I'm attempting to use this code I found...

```
pos.sortOn("cotangent", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);
```

...but I'm getting the error:

```
src/Main.hx:180: characters 2-12 : Array<{ yPoint : Float, xPoint : Float, cotangent : Float }> has no field sortOn
src/Main.hx:180: characters 26-39 : Class<Array> has no field NUMERIC
src/Main.hx:180: characters 42-58 : Class<Array> has no field DESCENDING
```

Now according to [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#Array()) 'sortOn' *is* an available method for AS3 arrays so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Haxe you could use [ArraySort](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/ds/ArraySort.html).
Something like [here](http://try.haxe.org/#40d7C)

Answer (score 0):

Haxe has a builtin standard Array class, which is what you're referencing, not AS3's Array. The Haxe Array is documented here: http://api.haxe.org/Array.html

If you don't care about a stable sort, you can use the sort method: http://api.haxe.org/Array.html#sort